# Setting up Google Map Fragment in Activity, but app keeps crashing now?

Tags: java, android, maps

I am attempting to add a Google Maps Api fragment, however, after reading through Google implementation, it is still crashing. Perhaps there is something I am missing in either the manifest, xml or source Java. I am new to Google API, however, am struggling to figure out the problem. Hopefully someone who has worked more with Google Api can help.

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="(I put my API here)"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    ........
    .......
    .....
```

XML:

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="341dp"
    android:layout_height="340dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.909"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.971" />
```

Java:

```java
public class ResumeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resume);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia,
        // and move the map's camera to the same location.
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
                .title("Marker in Sydney"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Comment: In your .xml layout file, try to change *class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"* to *android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"*

Comment: I changed that however in debugger it is still saying the error is from "mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);" saying that "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference"

Answer (score 1):

You can try **SupportMapFragment** instead of **MapFragment**.

```
 <fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="341dp"
android:layout_height="340dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.909"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.971" />
```

Comment: I changed the java from support to mapFragment and it worked, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use SupportMapFragment in xml instead of MapFragment

Comment: Why do you down vote my answer what's wrong with this tell me so I will take care next time